# Не ясно откуда пытается взять информацию запрос к бд

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь научиться работать с Entity и SQLite.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="Data Source=database.db;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Context:

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public PersonContext() : base("Model1")
        { }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

И собственно попытка обращения:

```
            repository Repository = new repository();
            IEnumerable<Person> records = from m in Repository.GetPersonList()
                                           select new Person
                                          {
                                              Id = m.Id,
                                              FIO = m.FIO,
                                              Club = m.Club,
                                              ChallengeName = m.ChallengeName,
                                              Place = m.Place,
                                              NumberOfMedals = m.NumberOfMedals
                                          };



            foreach (var item in records)
            {

                DataGridView.Rows.Add();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Id.ToString();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = FIO.ToString();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Club.ToString();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ChallengeName.ToString();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = Place.ToString();
                DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = NumberOfMedals.ToString();
                i++;
            }
```

На цикле `foreach` ловлю исключение:

```
SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: People
```

Но нигде не обращаюсь к таблице People, если быть точным, то такой таблицы вообще нет в базе данных. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `DbSet<Person>` - а это что? Никаких атрибутов переименования нет, поэтому провайдер ищет именно таблицу `Person`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, он ищет таблицу People, в том то и дело, не Person

Comment: А, ну да. Используется pluralize. Person во множественном числе будет People. Чтобы сказать больше, нужно видеть ваш код. Хотя бы какой подход используется: Code-first или DB-first? Как создавались таблицы? Как делается маппинг?

Comment: Покажите что у репозитория в методе GetPersonList()`

Comment: @Bulson, `public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonList()
            {
                return db.Persons;
            }`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, разобрался)